# My app is working well except for android 9 version. I can't understand what problem is

Tags: java, android, sdk, rss, version

I'm very new in Android. I have an app and working all devices well except for android 9 (Pie).

When tried to open this app it was crashed.

Here is my gradle and codes;

```
public class TestiFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final boolean GRID_LAYOUT = false;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private RssObject rssObject;
    private final String RSS_LINK = "http://www.herkul.org/category/kirik-testi/feed/";
    private final String RSS_TO_JSON_API = "http://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=";
    private TestiAdapter adapter;

    public static TestiFragment newInstance() {
        return new TestiFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.testi_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.testi_recycler);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //setup materialviewpager

        if (GRID_LAYOUT) {
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        }
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MaterialViewPagerHeaderDecorator());

        if(Common.isConnectedtoInternet(getActivity())){
            //loadRss();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Lütfen İnternet Bağlantınızı Kontrol Edin!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void loadRss() {
        AsyncTask<String, String, String> loadRssAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String result;
                HTTPDataHandler http = new HTTPDataHandler();
                result = http.getHTTPData(params[0]);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s, RssObject.class);
                adapter = new TestiAdapter(getActivity(), rssObject);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        StringBuilder url_Get_Data = new StringBuilder(RSS_TO_JSON_API);
        url_Get_Data.append(RSS_LINK);
        loadRssAsync.execute(url_Get_Data.toString());
    }

    public void removeFromFavorites(String name) {
        List<Item> items = this.rssObject.getItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
            if (items.get(i).title.equals(name)){
                this.adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my gradle;

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.herkultakip.jdevolope.herkultakip"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my logcat ;

```
 Process: com.herkultakip.jdevolope.herkultakip, PID: 9265
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.List com.herkultakip.jdevolope.herkultakip.Model.RssObject.items' on a null object reference
    at com.herkultakip.jdevolope.herkultakip.Adapter.TestiAdapter.getItemCount(TestiAdapter.java:71)
```

If you want anything to show you pls tell me :)

What is the problem of this error ?

But I dont understand why its not working on Andorid 9 while it works all devices ?

Comment: If the app crashes there is a corresponding Logcat entry. What does it say?

Comment: The information in logcat is useless. Error in loadRss() method. The application is running when I delete loadRss(). But this method is working in other devices very well. Also I have added logcat you can check it :)

Comment: Since the crash occurs in line 71 of TestiAdaspter.java, I guess something is null there which normally isn't. What about the *result* returned from `doInBackground()` - is it the same as with other android versions or did something go wrong with `http.getHTTPData(params[0]);` ?

Comment: result is null for Andorid 9. I have just notice that.  But why ? When I run it in two devices result is null for Android 9. The other device is 6 but result is ok.

Comment: If the HTTPDataHandler is the same as [this one](https://github.com/KurtisReid/android_app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/kreid/parsejsonblogspot/HTTPDataHandler.java), there could be some caught `Exception` (check the Logcat!). In this case, `getHTTPData()` can return `null`

Comment: yes, Its same. I will check it again !

Comment: One network related change with Pie is that it's no longer easy to use **http** instead of **https**, see this [blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html). I believe that's the reason for your issue.

Comment: thanks it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error is in the your `loadRss()` function.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

`ProgressDialog` has been deprecated since API 26. [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog)
You should use a progress indicator like `ProgressBar` instead for API's >= 26

This explains why it does work on all other android versions you tested.

Comment: According to your statement, If I remove progressDialog it needs to work. But it's still not working. But I like your answer, I didnt know that Progress Dialog has been deprecated. thanks.... The problem is result = null. but I dont know why!

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial by any chance? https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-parse-json-data-in-android.html

Comment: all of things are same brother :( No mistake according to tutorial